# Eval on variable causing illegal token

Tags: javascript, eval

I have the following variable set **as is**.

```
dialog.i_intro.value="Hi Im Jonathan<br />
<br />
Hi Im Jonathan<br />
<br />
Hi Im Jonathan";
```

To get there, I had to perform a string replace of `newlines` with `html breaks`. **I also tried performing this code with `newlines` and it produced the same result.** When I insert this javascript code into the `eval` function it breaks the code. **I cannot change the procedure of using the eval function**

Here is what i put into the **developer tools console**

```
    eval(dialog.i_intro.value="Hi Im Jonathan<br />
    <br />
    Hi Im Jonathan<br />
    <br />
    Hi Im Jonathan";);
```

I tested the code on the **developer tools console**

Here is what I put into the console.

Here is the output:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…)**

```
    with (typeof __commandLineAPI !== 'undefined' ? __commandLineAPI : { __proto__: null }) {
    eval(dialog.i_intro.value="Hi Im Jonathan<br />
    <br />
    Hi Im Jonathan<br />
    <br />
    Hi Im Jonathan";);
    }
```

Not quite sure what to do here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape newlines inside of your string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use newline `\n` characters in your JavaScript, not actual breaks in your string.

```
dialog.i_intro.value="Hi Im Jonathan<br />\n    <br />\n    Hi Im Jonathan<br />\n    <br />\n    Hi Im Jonathan";
```

*Note that the extra spaces in your string are due to it not being left aligned in your example.*

If you are using PHP server side your replace would look like the following. Notice that you need to escape the backslash in the replacement to print `\n` into the string.

```
$string = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $string);
```

Comment: How do you replace breaks with newlines?

Comment: You would need to do the replacement in the language that is printing your string, or if it is just HTML you need to write it as I did in the answer.